# How size Threejs canvas

Tags: three.js

I am trying to modify the canvas size changing

```
render.setsize(width,height);
```

but when I check canvas dimension on Chrome console it remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check the JavaScript console for errors?

The method is: renderer.set**S**ize(width, height)

Also make sure width and height is defined when the method is called.